# Component and UI suites for iOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, telerik

There are several HTML5 and .NET component suites out there that give you a framework to rapidly build applications. Some examples are http://sencha.com, http://kendoui.com, http://devexpress.com, http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx, and others.

Are there any good ones for iOS development? I found one from Telerik, but it only has 3 components at the moment: http://www.telerik.com/ios-ui. I was hoping for a bigger set and in Swift. Thanks for any help or direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) has a good number (10K+ iOS) of components that can either be used with the CocoaPods integration or grab the code and integrate yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) is a website that features lots of UI components, many of which are open source.